# Question about the cumulant expansion in Kardar's book

Tags: statistical-mechanics, statistics

I have one question relating to cumulant expansion when learning statistical mechanics using [Kardar's textbook](https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/physics/8-333-statistical-mechanics-i-statistical-mechanics-of-particles-fall-2013/lecture-notes/MIT8_333F13_Lec15.pdf).To calculate the partition function for intertacting system, it runs as following
[image]

The expectation value of a physical quantity $O$ can be calculated as(I will use the picture taken from his text book, where he use another notation, in order to clarify my question)
[image]

What confuses me is the footnote Kardar made here (not in the online notes, only can be seen in his book). In that note he explaisn the notation $\left\langle {O * {u^l}} \right\rangle _c^0$ which is the joint cumulant of random variable $O$ ann $u^l$ (he called it "connection function" in previous chapter)
[image]

Here I know that 
$$\left\langle {1 * {u^l}} \right\rangle _c^0 = \left\langle {1 \cdot {u^l}} \right\rangle  - \left\langle 1 \right\rangle \left\langle {{u^l}} \right\rangle  = 0 \ne \left\langle {{u^l}} \right\rangle _c^0$$

But for $\left\langle {1 * {u^0}} \right\rangle _c^0$, in my opinion, 
$$\left\langle {1 * {u^0}} \right\rangle _c^0 = \left\langle {1 \cdot {u^0}} \right\rangle  - \left\langle 1 \right\rangle \left\langle {{u^0}} \right\rangle  = \left\langle 1 \right\rangle  - \left\langle 1 \right\rangle \left\langle 1 \right\rangle  = 0$$.
Why Kardar gives $\left\langle {1 * {u^0}} \right\rangle _c^0=1$?